# Connecting ESP8266 to Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I connected my ESP8266 to my arduino as showed in this following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8pHpQSB1y4

In the arduino boards I chose the Generic ESP8266 Module with 115200 baud rate.
I tried to upload the following code, but everytime the it stucks on the Uploading with errors:
[code + errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJCRg.png)

What can I do to fix it?
I switched the RX and TX and make sure that the VCC is connected to 3.3V.
Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: Did you set boot mode of esp8266?

Comment: helppp @MertGülsoy

Comment: Which arduino board and esp module (ex. esp-12 or esp-01) are you using?

Comment: I do not know, I bought this one: https://nurdspace.nl/ESP8266

Answer (score 0):

As it seems from the question and comments:

- You're using ESP-01 module
- You try to use Arduino IDE to program/flash ESP-01 module

First check this out: [ESP-01 Cheat Sheet](http://img12.deviantart.net/4335/i/2015/337/e/2/esp8266_esp_01_module_pinout_diagram_cheat_sheet_by_adlerweb-d9iwm7a.png)

In order to flash any ESP chip you must do these:

- Pull GPIO0 low
- Pull GPIO15 low
- Pull GPIO2 high
  After doing these above, reset the chip and wait for 1 sec to boot.

Unfortunately you cannot flash the ESP-01 module from Serial interface since it has no GPIO15 exposed. If you want to flash ESP-01 you need to modify/add some connections to the circuit. As far as i know it comes preloaded with AT firmware. This AT firmware can be updated OTA when it is connected to internet.

Suggestion: try to get an ESP-12 or ESP-07

Answer (score 0):

From the video it seems that you are using ESP-01 chip
(i.e if your chip looks like the one in the video)
The code + Error screen shows that you are using Arduino IDE for flashing.

The error suggests that you are not bringing your chip to flash mode. Please refer to the circuit [RESET & PROG buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pZsp.png)
Steps to be Performed in Sequence

1. Compile your code
2. Connect your esp-01 as in circuit with FTDI
3. Connect with USB of your PC
4. Press & hold PROG Switch (i.e. Ground GPIO0)//keep it that way
5. Press & release RESET Switch(i.e. Ground your RST pin)
6. Press Upload in Arduino IDE
7. Wait for upload completion.
8. Release PROG Switch
9. Press & release RESET Switch
10. Your code should run

Please ensure that 3v3 power is supplied from an external source and not your USB. 
Connect LED to see the result of your code.